# App name is missing in MainActivity in ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, appcompatactivity

I can't figure out why the app name is missing in the action bar of main activity. I have set the label in the manifest like this:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

and the `style.xml`:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>



</resources>
```

I even added this to main activity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
...
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

}
```

but still the app name is not shown in the activity. All other activities have their labels displayed except main activity. Any ideas?

Comment: Silly question but just to verify - it is in your string.xml correctly?

Comment: @BR89 yes, I replaced it with hard coded string and still doesnt show it :(

Comment: Hm.. what was your initial Activity type when you first built? Is the Layout.xml the only file you have for your main activity?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
```

Comment: 20 second after posting my answer someone down vote it. I didn't figure that how fast the user is who run this code. Salute to that user.

Comment: I dont have enough rep points to vote but I tried this and still no title in the app bar. could it be the style file?

Comment: I know you didn't down vote. Try to use with `Toolbar`.

Comment: Try this link for Toolbar. http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/

Comment: If it is due to style then Check your app and activity didn't have theme NoActionBar.

Answer (score 0):

Set Title in onCreate() of your activity:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);            
toolbar.setTitle("My title");
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Change this :

```
android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
```

To:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

in activity tag in manifest.

Comment: I am using `getSupportActionBar`,

Comment: Then, I guess you are using toolbar. Try my edited answer.

Comment: I dont have a toolbar in my layout

Comment: not in app_bar_main.xml too ? If not change activity theme like above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in th manifest:

android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"

And see if shows the title. If you don't use a toolbar you don't need an actionbar